# Latex can't find tabularx even though it's installed

Tags: errors, tabularx

#### Description of Problem

When I use latexmk to compile a project to PDF I get the following error:

`` ! LaTeX Error: File `tablularx.sty' not found. ``

I am then prompted to "Enter file name". If I then enter the location of tabularx on disk (`/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty`) compilation proceeds a little further before I receive the same error and the same prompt again. If I enter the location of tabularx.sty each time I am prompted the compilation concludes successfully and my PDF appears as expected.

So the installation is functional, and tabularx is installed, but for some reason Latex can't find it by itself. This sounds like some sort of `PATH` issue to me, but some gentle experimentation got me nowhere, and I'm loathe to try anything more drastic when I don't really know what I'm doing.

#### Other notes

I've tried a bunch of troubleshooting steps and read up on a pile of similar-sounding errors but nothing has helped. Some things which may be worth noting:

- I installed MacTex 2016 (previously I was using MacTex 2015), and as far as I can tell the installation was successful.
- I updated my packages with `sudo tlmgr update --all`
- I've done basics like logging out and back in again etc.
- I edit my Latex source files in a text editor and compile them from the command line. I have never used any sort of GUI program to work with Latex on this system.
- `kpsewhich tabularx.sty` gives `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty`
- Running `sudo mktexlsr` updated a few things but did not solve the problem.
- `kpsewhich -var TEXMFDIST` gave `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist`
- Compiling the project manually without latexmk (Eg: `latex root.tex`) seems to run into the same error.
- `which pdflatex` gives `usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist`

#### System information

- Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.5
- MacTex 2015 installed from image at tug.org/mactex
- MacTex 2016 installed from image at tug.org/mactex

Comment: Welcome! What happens when you ***don't*** use `latexmk` and compile manually?  Have you tried `sudo mktexlsr` to ensure the filename database is current? This should be done at installation and update but it can't do any harm. What does `kpsewhich tabularx.sty` give? What does `kpsewhich -var TEXMFDIST` give? What about `which pdflatex`? Substitute relevant name for `pdflatex` if you're using something else.

Comment: If in doubt, blame the package's author ;).

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I've added some bullet points to "Other notes" in my question in response to your suggestions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is caused by a typo

Comment: As you wish  This question may still be useful for some people as it identifies troubleshooting steps and links the error message to a cause (a typo). There's no existing question which does that, and as a result I a) had no idea how to interpret the error message and b) had no idea how to go about troubleshooting it. Closing the question won't prevent that though, so no complaints from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a simple spelling mistake. The error message from the question contains a misspelled `tabularx`:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tablularx.sty' not found.
```

`tablularx` ⇒ `tabularx`

After correcting the package name in the source, the error message should go away.

Comment: Related: http://incolumitas.com/2016/06/08/typosquatting-package-managers/

Comment: @Rmano At least, in the TeX world, there is a some kind of review step for new packages in CTAN and probably most if not all TeX distributions (TeX Live, MiKTeX, ...). For example, licenses needs to be classified, an entry in the TeX catalogue needs to be made, ...